Can not change address members, the change is in conflict with policy
When I try to add an address to an address group i get this:
Value conflicts with system settings
Can not change address members, the change is in conflict with policy.
However I cannot find anything what does this indicate?


Please provide sanitized output of both the object your trying to add to the group and the group itself and the firmware version you're running on.
Also please try adding the object using cli with the following commands as that often provides different and more specific error messages
config firewall addrgrp
    edit {grpname}
        append member {addrobject to append}
    next
end

